# What the does this strange RESEDIT error mean and how do I fix it (Error:Line 16:SUBLANG_NEUTRAL:undeclared identifier)?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I tried to make a GUI program using Code::Blocks and ResEdit.

I have been trying to open the resource.c file (resource file in the which automatically comes into the project folder after the project is created) with ResEdit and I don't know why I am constantly failing.

Is showing this error: "Line 16 : SUBLANG NEUTRAL : undeclared identifier"

Earlier, it was showing that windows.h header file was not present in the include path. So I guess that I have to download windows.h file and paste it in the include folder. What do you think??

Comment: some code please, minimal to reproduce the problem.

Comment: _So I guess that I have to download windows.h file_ Bad idea! `windows.h` is the "entry point" into the win32 API and there are a lot more stuff you need. You have to install a Windows SDK. FYI: [Microsoft Windows SDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK), [MS: Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/)

Answer (score 0):

In the ResEdit Preferences set path to the "include" folder in the MinGW directory. I mean that "include" where the "windows.h" file is.